# Overlapping Constraint Names in Pulp Issues

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

I am modifying some code I got from this [GitHub](https://github.com/wpbSabi/python_optimization/blob/main/oregon_districts/towardsDS/Gists_Model_Follow_Along.ipynb) to look at redistricting the congressional districts in Illinois. When I try to define the constraint names (in Section 4) I keep getting an error 'PulpError: overlapping constraint names: Allocation_assignment_110'. I've tried looking for duplicate rows or assignments and I can't find anything. Can anyone see what's going wrong here or have suggestions for how to check what could be going wrong? (I'm pretty new to Pulp and not that efficient at error checking yet)

The Problem Code Below (also found [here](https://github.com/tktownes/Illinois_Algorithmic_Redistricting/blob/main/AlgorithmicRedistricting.py) on GitHub) -

```
# Section 4: constraints
# Initial Assignment / Allocation Constraints

## Allocate 100% of the population from each county.
for i in range(n_counties):
    model += lpSum(allocation[i][j] for j in range(n_districts)) == county_populations[i] , "" + str(i)
    
# This constraint makes assignment required for allocation.
# At least 20% of population must be allocated for any assignment.
for i in range(n_counties): 
    for j in range(n_districts):
        model += allocation[i][j] <= sum(county_populations)*assignment[i][j] , "Allocation assignment " + str(i) + str(j)
        if assignment[i][j] == 1:
            model += allocation[i][j] >= assignment[i][j]*0.20*county_populations[i] , "Allocation min " + str(i) + str(j)

# Contiguous districts constraints
# e.g. Coos County (5) borders only Curry County (7) or Douglas County (8)
#      Therefore at least (7) or (8) need to be allocated to any district that has (5)
# a 2* in front of the left hand 'assignment' means the county is required to border at least two counties from the same district
for j in range(n_districts):
    model += assignment[0][j] <= assignment[83][j]+assignment[4][j]+assignment[74][j]+assignment[33][j] 
    model += assignment[1][j] <= assignment[90][j]+assignment[76][j] 
    model += assignment[2][j] <= assignment[56][j]+assignment[67][j]+assignment[25][j]+assignment[13][j]
    model += assignment[3][j] <= assignment[100][j]+assignment[19][j]+assignment[62][j]  ## consider Ogle (70)
    model += assignment[4][j] <= assignment[0][j]+assignment[83][j]+assignment[8][j]+assignment[68][j]+assignment[74][j]
    model += assignment[5][j] <= assignment[36][j]+assignment[97][j]+assignment[51][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[77][j]+assignment[58][j]+assignment[87][j]
    model += assignment[6][j] <= assignment[74][j]+assignment[30][j]+assignment[41][j]  ## consider for a 2*
    model += assignment[7][j] <= assignment[42][j]+assignment[88][j]+assignment[70][j]+assignment[97][j]
    model += assignment[8][j] <= assignment[83][j]+assignment[59][j]+assignment[64][j]+assignment[68][j]+assignment[4][j]
    model += assignment[9][j] <= assignment[63][j]+assignment[26][j]+assignment[91][j]+assignment[20][j]+assignment[73][j]  ## consider Edgar(22)
    model += assignment[10][j] <= assignment[82][j]+assignment[54][j]+assignment[85][j]+assignment[67][j]
    model += assignment[11][j] <= assignment[16][j]+assignment[39][j]+assignment[17][j]+assignment[14][j]+assignment[22][j]
    model += assignment[12][j] <= assignment[25][j]+assignment[24][j]+assignment[39][j]+assignment[79][j]+assignment[95][j]+assignment[57][j]
    model += assignment[13][j] <= assignment[2][j]+assignment[25][j]+assignment[57][j]+assignment[94][j]+assignment[86][j]+assignment[56][j]
    model += assignment[14][j] <= assignment[69][j]+assignment[20][j]+assignment[22][j]+assignment[11][j]+assignment[17][j]+assignment[85][j]
    model += assignment[15][j] <= assignment[48][j]+assignment[21][j]+assignment[44][j]+assignment[98][j]
    model += assignment[16][j] <= assignment[11][j]+assignment[39][j]+assignment[50][j]
    model += assignment[17][j] <= assignment[85][j]+assignment[14][j]+assignment[11][j]+assignment[39][j]+assignment[24][j]
    model += assignment[18][j] <= assignment[63][j]+assignment[73][j]+assignment[54][j]+assignment[53][j]
    model += assignment[19][j] <= assignment[44][j]+assignment[46][j]+assignment[62][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[51][j]+assignment[70][j]
    model += assignment[20][j] <= assignment[9][j]+assignment[22][j]+assignment[14][j]+assignment[69][j]+assignment[73][j]
    model += assignment[21][j] <= assignment[15][j]+assignment[98][j]+assignment[44][j]
    model += assignment[22][j] <= assignment[91][j]+assignment[11][j]+assignment[14][j]+assignment[20][j]
    model += assignment[23][j] <= assignment[79][j]+assignment[92][j]+assignment[96][j]+assignment[95][j]
    model += assignment[24][j] <= assignment[25][j]+assignment[85][j]+assignment[39][j]+assignment[12][j]+assignment[17][j]
    model += assignment[25][j] <= assignment[2][j]+assignment[67][j]+assignment[85][j]+assignment[24][j]+assignment[57][j]+assignment[13][j]+assignment[12][j]  ## relook at 12 after first run
    model += assignment[26][j] <= assignment[45][j]+assignment[37][j]+assignment[91][j]+assignment[9][j]+assignment[63][j]+assignment[52][j]
    model += assignment[27][j] <= assignment[72][j]+assignment[40][j]+assignment[32][j]+assignment[38][j]+assignment[99][j]+assignment[81][j]  ## watch 81 and consider a 2*
    model += assignment[28][j] <= assignment[61][j]+assignment[93][j]+assignment[47][j]+assignment[71][j]+assignment[89][j]+assignment[83][j]+assignment[59][j]
    model += assignment[29][j] <= assignment[34][j]+assignment[81][j]+assignment[96][j]   ## consider Hamilton County (32)
    model += assignment[30][j] <= assignment[74][j]+assignment[84][j]+assignment[68][j]+assignment[55][j]+assignment[41][j]+assignment[6][j]
    model += assignment[31][j] <= assignment[49][j]+assignment[46][j]+assignment[52][j]+assignment[45][j]+assignment[98][j]
    model += assignment[32][j] <= assignment[27][j]+assignment[40][j]+assignment[95][j]+assignment[96][j]+assignment[81][j] ## consider Gallatin County (29)
    model += assignment[33][j] <= assignment[35][j]+assignment[61][j]+assignment[83][j]+assignment[0][j]
    model += assignment[34][j] <= assignment[75][j]+assignment[81][j]+assignment[29][j]  ## consider a 2* assignment
    model += assignment[35][j] <= assignment[65][j]+assignment[33][j]+assignment[61][j]+assignment[93][j]
    model += assignment[36][j] <= assignment[80][j]+assignment[97][j]+assignment[5][j]+assignment[87][j]+assignment[47][j]+assignment[65][j]
    model += assignment[37][j] <= assignment[45][j]+assignment[26][j]+assignment[91][j]
    model += assignment[38][j] <= assignment[78][j]+assignment[72][j]+assignment[27][j]+assignment[99][j]+assignment[90][j]
    model += assignment[39][j] <= assignment[12][j]+assignment[24][j]+assignment[17][j]+assignment[16][j]+assignment[79][j]+assignment[11][j]  ## consider 50
    model += assignment[40][j] <= assignment[94][j]+assignment[57][j]+assignment[95][j]+assignment[32][j]+assignment[27][j]+assignment[72][j]
    model += assignment[41][j] <= assignment[6][j]+assignment[30][j]+assignment[55][j]+assignment[56][j]
    model += assignment[42][j] <= assignment[7][j]+assignment[88][j]
    model += assignment[43][j] <= assignment[76][j]+assignment[60][j]+assignment[75][j]+assignment[99][j]+assignment[90][j]   ## consider Saline County (81)
    model += assignment[44][j] <= assignment[19][j]+assignment[62][j]+assignment[15][j]+assignment[21][j]+assignment[46][j]
    model += assignment[45][j] <= assignment[98][j]+assignment[37][j]+assignment[26][j]+assignment[52][j]+assignment[31][j]
    model += assignment[46][j] <= assignment[19][j]+assignment[44][j]+assignment[98][j]+assignment[31][j]  ## consider DuPage (21)
    model += assignment[47][j] <= assignment[65][j]+assignment[36][j]+assignment[93][j]+assignment[28][j]+assignment[71][j]+assignment[87][j]
    model += assignment[48][j] <= assignment[62][j]+assignment[15][j]
    model += assignment[49][j] <= assignment[51][j]+assignment[19][j]+assignment[46][j]+assignment[31][j]+assignment[52][j]+assignment[58][j]+assignment[101][j]
    model += assignment[50][j] <= assignment[16][j]+assignment[79][j]+assignment[92][j]
    model += assignment[51][j] <= assignment[70][j]+assignment[19][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[5][j]+assignment[97][j]
    model += assignment[52][j] <= assignment[45][j]+assignment[26][j]+assignment[63][j]+assignment[101][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[31][j]
    model += assignment[53][j] <= assignment[89][j]+assignment[18][j]+assignment[54][j]+assignment[82][j]+assignment[64][j]+assignment[59][j]+assignment[63][j]
    model += assignment[54][j] <= assignment[53][j]+assignment[18][j]+assignment[73][j]+assignment[69][j]+assignment[85][j]+assignment[10][j]+assignment[82][j]
    model += assignment[55][j] <= assignment[41][j]+assignment[30][j]+assignment[68][j]+assignment[82][j]+assignment[67][j]+assignment[56][j]
    model += assignment[56][j] <= assignment[41][j]+assignment[55][j]+assignment[67][j]+assignment[2][j]+assignment[13][j]+assignment[86][j]
    model += assignment[57][j] <= assignment[25][j]+assignment[12][j]+assignment[95][j]+assignment[40][j]+assignment[13][j]  ## consider Washington County (94)
    model += assignment[58][j] <= assignment[87][j]+assignment[5][j]+assignment[77][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[101][j]+assignment[71][j]
    model += assignment[59][j] <= assignment[28][j]+assignment[89][j]+assignment[53][j]+assignment[64][j]+assignment[8][j]+assignment[83][j]   ## consider a 2* or removing Schuyler (83)
    model += assignment[60][j] <= assignment[76][j]+assignment[43][j]+assignment[75][j]
    model += assignment[61][j] <= assignment[33][j]+assignment[35][j]+assignment[93][j]+assignment[83][j]+assignment[28][j]
    model += assignment[62][j] <= assignment[3][j]+assignment[19][j]+assignment[44][j]+assignment[48][j] ##consider cook county (15)
    model += assignment[63][j] <= assignment[101][j]+assignment[52][j]+assignment[26][j]+assignment[9][j]+assignment[73][j]+assignment[53][j]+assignment[18][j]
    model += assignment[64][j] <= assignment[59][j]+assignment[53][j]+assignment[82][j]+assignment[8][j]
    model += assignment[65][j] <= assignment[80][j]+assignment[93][j]+assignment[35][j]+assignment[36][j]+assignment[47][j]
    model += assignment[66][j] <= assignment[86][j]+assignment[78][j]
    model += assignment[67][j] <= assignment[55][j]+assignment[82][j]+assignment[10][j]+assignment[85][j]+assignment[25][j]+assignment[2][j]+assignment[56][j]
    model += assignment[68][j] <= assignment[8][j]+assignment[82][j]+assignment[55][j]+assignment[30][j]+assignment[84][j]
    model += assignment[69][j] <= assignment[54][j]+assignment[73][j]+assignment[20][j]+assignment[14][j]+assignment[85][j]
    model += assignment[70][j] <= assignment[19][j]+assignment[100][j]+assignment[51][j]+assignment[88][j]+assignment[7][j]+assignment[97][j]  ## consider a 2* for this one and possibly Boone (3)
    model += assignment[71][j] <= assignment[87][j]+assignment[89][j]+assignment[101][j]+assignment[58][j]+assignment[47][j]+assignment[28][j]
    model += assignment[72][j] <= assignment[78][j]+assignment[94][j]+assignment[40][j]+assignment[27][j]+assignment[38][j]
    model += assignment[73][j] <= assignment[63][j]+assignment[9][j]+assignment[20][j]+assignment[69][j]+assignment[54][j]+assignment[18][j]
    model += assignment[74][j] <= assignment[0][j]+assignment[4][j]+assignment[84][j]+assignment[30][j]+assignment[6][j]
    model += assignment[75][j] <= assignment[43][j]+assignment[81][j]+assignment[34][j]+assignment[60][j]
    model += assignment[76][j] <= assignment[1][j]+assignment[90][j]+assignment[43][j]+assignment[60][j]
    model += assignment[77][j] <= assignment[5][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[58][j]
    model += assignment[78][j] <= assignment[66][j]+assignment[86][j]+assignment[94][j]+assignment[72][j]+assignment[38][j]
    model += assignment[79][j] <= assignment[12][j]+assignment[30][j]+assignment[50][j]+assignment[92][j]+assignment[23][j]+assignment[95][j]
    model += assignment[80][j] <= assignment[97][j]+assignment[65][j]+assignment[36][j]
    model += assignment[81][j] <= assignment[99][j]+assignment[27][j]+assignment[32][j]+assignment[29][j]+assignment[34][j]+assignment[75][j]  ## consider Johnson County (43)
    model += assignment[82][j] <= assignment[64][j]+assignment[53][j]+assignment[54][j]+assignment[10][j]+assignment[67][j]+assignment[55][j]+assignment[68][j]
    model += assignment[83][j] <= assignment[33][j]+assignment[61][j]+assignment[28][j]+assignment[59][j]+assignment[8][j]+assignment[4][j]+assignment[0][j]
    model += assignment[84][j] <= assignment[74][j]+assignment[68][j]+assignment[30][j]
    model += assignment[85][j] <= assignment[10][j]+assignment[54][j]+assignment[69][j]+assignment[14][j]+assignment[17][j]+assignment[24][j]+assignment[25][j]+assignment[67][j]
    model += assignment[86][j] <= assignment[56][j]+assignment[13][j]+assignment[94][j]+assignment[78][j]+assignment[66][j]
    model += assignment[87][j] <= assignment[71][j]+assignment[58][j]+assignment[47][j]+assignment[36][j]+assignment[5][j]
    model += assignment[88][j] <= assignment[42][j]+assignment[7][j]+assignment[70][j]+assignment[100][j]
    model += assignment[89][j] <= assignment[71][j]+assignment[101][j]+assignment[63][j]+assignment[53][j]+assignment[59][j]+assignment[28][j]
    model += assignment[90][j] <= assignment[38][j]+assignment[99][j]+assignment[43][j]+assignment[76][j]+assignment[1][j]
    model += assignment[91][j] <= assignment[37][j]+assignment[26][j]+assignment[9][j]+assignment[22][j]  ## consider Douglas (20)
    model += assignment[92][j] <= assignment[50][j]+assignment[23][j]  ## consider Richland Count (79) and/or a 2* assignment
    model += assignment[93][j] <= assignment[65][j]+assignment[35][j]+assignment[61][j]+assignment[28][j]+assignment[47][j]
    model += assignment[94][j] <= assignment[86][j]+assignment[13][j]+assignment[40][j]+assignment[72][j]+assignment[78][j]  ## consider Marion County (57)
    model += assignment[95][j] <= assignment[57][j]+assignment[12][j]+assignment[79][j]+assignment[23][j]+assignment[96][j]+assignment[32][j]+assignment[40][j]
    model += assignment[96][j] <= assignment[32][j]+assignment[95][j]+assignment[23][j]+assignment[29][j]  ## consider Saline County (81)
    model += assignment[97][j] <= assignment[7][j]+assignment[70][j]+assignment[51][j]+assignment[5][j]+assignment[36][j]+assignment[80][j]  ## consider removing Ogle County [70]
    model += assignment[98][j] <= assignment[15][j]+assignment[21][j]+assignment[45][j]+assignment[31][j]+assignment[46][j]
    model += assignment[99][j] <= assignment[90][j]+assignment[38][j]+assignment[27][j]+assignment[81][j]+assignment[43][j]  ## consider Pope County (75)
    model += assignment[100][j] <= assignment[88][j]+assignment[70][j]+assignment[3][j]   ## consider DeKalb (19)
    model += assignment[101][j] <= assignment[89][j]+assignment[71][j]+assignment[58][j]+assignment[49][j]+assignment[52][j]+assignment[63][j]

    
# District size constraints, in order to keep the size of districts by population similar
for j in range(n_districts):
    model += lpSum(allocation[i][j] for i in range(n_counties)) <= 800000 , "District Size Maximum " + str(j)
    model += lpSum(allocation[i][j] for i in range(n_counties)) >= 700000 , "District Size Minimum " + str(j)

# Only allow counties that meet certain critera to be split among multiple districts
# A county must have population > 220,000 to be split among up to two districts
for i in range(n_counties): # added
    if county_populations[i] <= 220000: 
        model += lpSum(assignment[i][j] for j in range(n_districts)) <= 1  , "Unique Assignment " + str(i) 
    else:
        model += lpSum(assignment[i][j] for j in range(n_districts)) <= 2  , "Up-to-two Assignments " + str(i)
```

[PulpError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ibta.jpg)

I am looking for either a solution or a few ways to error check myself, like a way to print what/where the exact error is (I've already manually looked for duplicate names and checked the syntax for any errors).
Any help really would be great.
Thanks!! :)

Comment: After you fix the names….  Is your “contiguousness” constraint working???  I have my doubts…

Answer (score 0):

Your labeling mechanism is "busted" for lack of a better term and creating conflicts.  In the last line below:

```
# At least 20% of population must be allocated for any assignment.
for i in range(n_counties): 
    for j in range(n_districts):
        model += allocation[i][j] <= sum(county_populations)*assignment[i][j] , "Allocation assignment " + str(i) + str(j)
```

You are concatenating the string value of 2 integers to label this constraint.  However, this is not unique with the values of `i`, and `j` you have.  The combinations of (1, 10), (11, 0) both produce the same label and conflict.  Consider adding a separator in the middle like this:

```
model += allocation[i][j] <= sum(county_populations)*assignment[i][j] , "Allocation assignment " + str(i) + "_" +str(j)
```

After you fix that, you will realize you have the same conflict in your `variable_names` and you'll need to fix that with a similar tweak as well.